# How to use in replacement String in replaceAll method a matched text?

Tags: java, regex, string

I would like to add some text after matched pattern in String. How can I do this?
for example: `String text = text.replaceAll("a[0-9]*z",???+"ADDED"); // a123z -> a123zADDED`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String text = text.replaceAll("a[0-9]*z", "$0ADDED");
```

**See also:**

- [`Matcher.appendReplacement()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29)